# Ubuntu 12.04.2 hangs during boot on a pink screen, console mode is blank

Tags: installation, grub2, uefi, 12.04

I've installed 12.04.2 on a OS-less Asus B85M-E (Intel Core i5-4430 [LGA1150]). When I boot, it freezes on a 'pink screen'. Alt-Ctrl-F1 has no output.

i have already reinstalled once. I read in many forum posts that some specific UEFI features cause problems with Ubuntu and GRUB and should be disabled before installation. So I disabled Fast Boot and Intel SRT, and then reinstalled. Secure boot was enabled when I installed a second time. Successful reinstallation, same freeze-up on reboot. I've since confirmed that Fast Boot, SRT and also Secure Boot are disabled. No change when booting.

Should I reinstall again? Should I use a later version of Ubuntu and the Linux kernel? Should I disable anything else?

Also, are there any guides on the UEFI BIOS menu for this Asus motherboard. It has so many options and many exotic names. The last machine I installed Ubuntu (12.04) on was a Celeron laptop, so this is all very fancy. It would be nice to know which options can or cannot be used with Linux.

Thanks for your help.

Ryan

Comment: If you are the same Ryan that answered - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page and request that your two accounts are merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing on a disk with GPT partition table, you will need EFI-partition. Take a look at "Creating an EFI partition" in here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

You may also install boot loader on a different disk with legacy MBR partition table (e.g. USB flash drive).